# transfer to another location retention not working sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, retention

I have a configured a retention policy on a document library, the document should be moved to another location (Drop Off library) after certain amount of time. This doesnt seem to be working.
Please note that I have configured the Content organizer feature and "Send To" connections in Central Admin. I also have changed the trigger time for Information Policy and expiration policy job to run every 2 mins and 5 mins respectively.

Am i missing anything, because the functionality is not working and there is no error being thrown. All i can see is that the retention action is displayed as completed in "Compliance details" tab after sometime, but documents havent moved to drop off library. Also other retention action such as move to recycle bin work perfectly fine.

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If Move to recycle bin is working but Transfer isn't, I'm assuming your destination site is the same as the source. If so, this is not going to work because according to Microsoft support

**It was as per design**. If you try to move documents to a different location using Retention policy, you have to move it a library in a **different site collection**. Preferably ‘Records center‘ site collection. Main idea of Microsoft is to have one Archival or Records center site collection for the whole organization.

So, if you are trying to move documents after expiration to a library in same site or site collection, you can use a workaround to start a workflow on expiration date which moves the document to archival library.

Hope this helps. [Source](http://sharepointviews.com/sharepoint-retention-policy-not-working-solved/)

Comment: This is correct in 2010 as well, not sure why the setup documents are still not very clear about this, but almost every retention policy except for start a workflow does not work within the same site collection.

Answer (score 0):

To start with  for investigation

1.There are two timer job services in Sharepoint 2010 ( it looks the same on 2013 as well) so ... "Information management policy" and "Expiration policy". check if these Job are working as desired for the web application. I understand it works partially on some instances. But I don't know if it is on the same webapp level.

2. Next can you check if these documents are checked-out to some one on the team or to a person who has left the firm which is very common sometime User Profile service may give you tickle by not syncing as desired.
3. If you have custom content type for which the the document is saved. then if the same content type exist on the destination folder ( drop off lib) where document to be moved.

I had a situation when the documents where located inside a folder (leaf) inside document library. Move of document expected a same folder on destination which was weird. But after changing folder name which had '(' symbol it worked.

I have also seen some instances of permissions to the folder for the timer job but, I did not have that experience.

Without actual settings on the retention policy I can only give only pointers. Therefore, please give bit more information about the retention policy setup if it is not confidential.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The issue still persists.  

1) Both the jobs run at frequent intervals with Information management policy running every 2 minutes and Expiration Policy every 4 minutes.  
2) All the documents are checked in. 
3) There are no custom content types used, my policies for default document content type. 


I have given the condition in retention action to move to the drop off library after "Created + 0 days" for testing purpose. Ideally the document should move to drop off library once both the jobs run, but that's not the case. 
Thanks again.

Comment: It is worth creating a simple workflow on the source document library using SharePoint designer to move document to drop library. you could say for example  created is more than certain time( probale minutes) and configure an action move document to drop off library. You could catch the error when workflow runs.

Comment: Noticed a issue - The transfer to another location works perfectly fine if the drop off library location is in another Site Collection. But doesn't work if pointed to drop off library in the same site collection. 

 I created a retention policy for Library1 in Site Collection 1 that has Drop Off libraryy1 , it didn't work. But if give the destination as Drop off library 2 in Site collection 2 then the retention policy for Library1 works fine. Any idea why this is happening? 

 Thank You

Comment: This is weird. Is "Library and Folder Based Retention" under site collection Feature is enabled?

Comment: Yes "Library and Folder Based Retention" is active on both the site collections. 

  Regarding the earlier query about trying with a workflow (Same action of copying a document to drop off library). The workflow copies the document but cancels out with message - "The workflow operation failed because the action requires the document to be checked out."

Comment: The workflow issue has been solved ,  I set "Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited?" to "NO". The workflow now copies the documents without any error. However the transfer to another location issue still doesn't move to drop off library in the same site collection. Thank you

Comment: is it that "Send to Connection" we configure in central admin, work only for external source (different site collection)?

Comment: Noop it is for another site collection, another library if configured with properly with managed path you can use with another sp web application. They way the send to connection works is it uses Object model to copy the recent or current version of document or item to destination. I'm not sure if your question is related to this thread if not please add your question as a Seperate thread so that others can benefit. otherwise sorry, please ignore my suggestion.

Comment: Oops I forgot to mention please  make sure app pool account is a member ( atleast have add/ edit permission) to add item or document in the destination library. I remember a bug surrounding this but I'm not sure if MS has fixed on one of its service.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, and after lots of try and error I found up that I have a required column in the destination content type which wasn't required in the source content type. Just check it!